# Performance de JSON para alimentar todo um site

Tags: jquery, json

Adaptando um tema Drupal para HTML puro com um cronograma apertado, como já era de se esperar, o código saiu um pouco mais complicado do que eu gostaria.

Dessa forma, tive oportunidade de explorar o JSON e algumas de suas funcionalidades
e decidi criar um arquivo `data.json` para alimentar todos os textos do site e possibilitar, além da edição fácil destes, em um futuro próximo o suporte a outras línguas.

Segue trecho do JSON para análise:

```
{"Textos": {
            "TituloDestaque":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,",
            "CorpoDestaque":"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>",
            "Sobre1":"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>",
            "Sobre2":"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>",
}}
```

**Isso afeta negativamente a performance de um site de médio a grande porte?**

O link que tive acesso para testar é *bruto*, por falta de palavra melhor, portanto não obtive uma métrica conclusiva.

Estou falando da ordem de 200~300 parágrafos parametrizados em um arquivo JSON chamado por 8~10 páginas para sites médios e 750~1000 parágrafos em 20+ páginas em sites grandes.

Caso não seja correto resolver dessa forma, qual seria a opção sem fazer uso de BD?

Comment: Acredito que isso vai ficar ruin para os clientes, pois o json vai ser processado pelo navegador e não pelo servidor que entregaria tudo pronto, sendo assim a performance site seria de baixo desempenho para computadores menos robustos mas descarregaria o servidor, o bom mesmo seria equilibrar o trabalho dos mesmos

Comment: @FelipeFonseca agora que vi que é um site de html puro... considerando isso você tem duas opçõesm xml ou json, e acho que json realmente é a melhor opção entre as duas...

Comment: http://www.ziggytech.net/technology/web-development/how-big-is-too-big-for-json/

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca Edição de código que melhorem a legibilidade sem alterar a lógica são benvindas! Eu alterei o código quebrando linhas **sem alterar a lógica** para evitar o scroll. Veja mais em http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/749

Comment: @andre-figueiredo Mas alterou a lógica. Meu JScript utiliza aqueles marcadores, cada um deles.

Comment: Leia a resposta do @Gabe

Comment: @andre-figueiredo seu link nos comentários explica exatamente o que eu gostaria. Peço que por favor formule uma resposta utilizando ele que será um prazer aceitá-la e o +1.

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca ah, certo! devo ter removido sem querer os identificadores.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Desde que o seu site é HTML puro, acredito que você não tenha muita saída.
[Segundo este link](http://www.ziggytech.net/technology/web-development/how-big-is-too-big-for-json/), um JSON com cerca de 1000 parágrafos (~700KB) deve usar cerca de:
15MB no IE
35MB no Chrome
200MB no Firefox

Em um i7 o processamento está na ordem de dezenas de milissegundos num MacBook Pro Core i7 2.2GHz.
Como não foi o dito o perfil dos usuários (sistema interno x aberto, máquinas), deduzo que pela média brasileira dos PCs há grandes chances desse valor ser multiplicado.
Como haverá a transformação dos parágrafos em JSON para HTML e eles são parametrizados, irá ter mais adição de milissegundos no carregamento da página.

Sugiro, carregar o JSON assincronamente e durante o carregamento dar um feedback para o usuário (por exemplo "Carregando conteúdo..."), para não trancar a página para o usuário e informar-lo que o conteúdo que não está visível à primeira vista está em processo de carregamento.

Ainda sugiro, que faça um carregamento por demanda (muito usado atualmente), do estilo de "timeline" do Facebook.
Não sei se será possível no seu layout, mas a dica é que inicialmente carregue os primeiros parágrafos - ou um conteúdo o suficiente para ocupar uma tela e o usuário enquanto carrega o resto. E depois carregue os outros sucessivamente a medida que o usuário role a página (por demanda) ou em sequencia mesma no código.

Comment: Acredito que para diminuir a carga vou ter separar em vários arquivos, um para cada página ao invés de carregar 700kb em um só tiro. Quanto ao feedback, perfeito, era exatamente o que eu procurava.

Comment: Sim, e carregue sucessivamente.

Answer (score 1):

Como sugestão:

já tentou usar o http://jekyllrb.com/, ele é um CMS que não trabalha com DB, 
para roda-lo localmente tu precisa de ruby e python, depois da postagem pronta,
tu faz um build ("compila") e ele gera os arquivos html.

O GitHub usa esse cara:

Exemplo: http://brunorozendo.com.br

Repositório: https://github.com/brunorozendo/brunorozendo.github.io

Comment: Parece promissor! Vou dar uma olhada com calma.